# Using an IF-Statement inside a drawtext (FFMPEG)

Tags: if-statement, ffmpeg, textbox, drawtext

I'm currently trying to implement a timer on a video with FFMPEG, so it should start at 00.00 and start timing after a number of frames and stop timing again after a set amount of frames. So the timer should work like this:

`00:00` `00:00` `00.00` (start timing) `00.01` `00.02` `[...]` `05.88` `05.89` (stop timing) `05.89` `05.89` `05.89`

So far I've got the following as (minimal) command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 
-filter_complex "[0:v]drawtext=fontfile='C\\:font.ttf':
text='%{eif\\:n/30\\:d\\:2}\\:%{eif\\:((mod(n,30))/30)*100\\:d\\:2}':
fontcolor=black:fontsize=55:x=(1705.5-(text_w/2)):y=(1000.5-(text_h/2)),format=yuv420p" 
-pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy out.mp4
```

There is some more stuff inside of the filter_complex, so I can't replace that with `-vf` or similar.

Thanks for all of your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you want to start the count at `n=200` and end at `n=700`. Then let's call `min(max(n-200,0),700-200)` as X

Your text expression now becomes

```
text='%{eif\\:X/30\\:d\\:2}\\:%{eif\\:((mod(X,30))/30)*100\\:d\\:2}'
```

Comment: Can you please explain the need for the double backslashes? Thank you, regards.